Understanding UTC time in js
Backend give me data of gantt diagramm start and end points in format:
"horizont_start": "2024-05-01T00:00:00Z",
"horizont_end": "2025-01-26T00:00:00Z",
Next i give through props to another component Date format of this points like this:
<NewGanttChart
    start={
        new Date(
            gantt?.horizont_start ||
                new Date(
                    new Date().getFullYear(),
                    0,
                    1
                )
        )
    }
    end={
        new Date(
            gantt?.horizont_end ||
                new Date()
        )
    }
    data={gantt?.machine_types || []}
    isTooltip={true}
    tooltip={tooltip}
/>

in component i use function to calculate timeAxis intervals:
//also save in store start and end time
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(setStartTime(start?.getTime()))
        dispatch(setEndTime(end?.getTime()))
    }, [start, end])
 const timeAxis = useMemo(() => {
       
        const axisLength = Math.ceil((end - start) / (measure * 60 * 60 * 1000))

        const axisDates = new Array(axisLength).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
            const date = new Date(start.getTime())
            const newDate = new Date(+date + 1000 * 60 * 60 * measure * i)

            return newDate.getTime()
        })

        console.log(axisDates)

        return axisDates
    }, [end, measure, start])

My main problem is local time, so i want to show start point time 00:00:00, but i got +5h 05:00:00, how to solve this problem?
PS: one more time with logs
console.log(gantt?.horizont_start) // output 2024-05-01T00:00:00Z

console.log(new Date(gantt?.horizont_start)) // output Wed May 01 2024 05:00:00 GMT+0500 (Uzbekistan Standard Time)



are you in a UTC+5 timezone

Yes, that's right

There isn't any point in calling the Date constructor on a timestamp (new Date(start.getTime())) only to turn around and convert it back to a number on the next line. Also note that while JS date objects are always internally UTC, logging them to the console displays a local time string. Use .toISOString()

What is NewGanttChart doing with those dates? Where are they output as "+5h 05:00:00"?

NewGanttChart have timeAxis function and also write to redux store getTime() from start and end  Date format points.

This time conversions are always very confusing and easy to fail especially in javascript. :(

@OzanBAYRAM most other languages aren't any better. Timezones just suck.

@JaredSmith C# has a bajillion ways for you to mess up time. You can create a datetime which is in UTC or local or just ¯\(ツ)/¯. And you might not even know what it is. Various ways to get some sort of common time might shift what you currently have or not depending on how you've done it. By comparison, Java had at least three different ways to handle data time. Adding new ones because the old ones were wrong. So yes - it sucks all around.

The time 00:00:00 UTC is the same moment in time as 05:00:00 in a +5h time zone.
To solve you issue you'll probably want to be working with the UTC representation. To do this replace the Date methods you're using to their UTC variants:

getUTCDate()/setUTCDate()
getUTCDay()
getUTCFullYear()/setUTCFullYear
getUTCHours()/setUTCHours()
getUTCMilliseconds()/setUTCMilliseconds()
getUTCMinutes()/setUTCMinutes()
getUTCMonth()/setUTCMonth()
getUTCSeconds()/setUTCSeconds()

To log/display the time you can use toUTCString() or toISOString(), depending on the preferred format.
Working with the above methods lets you work with the same time zone that the server provides. Meaning that time doesn't jump, assuming the server always provides UTC time.
// assuming your time zone is set to Uzbekistan Standard Time
new Date("2024-05-01T00:00:00Z").getHours() //=> 5
new Date("2024-05-01T00:00:00Z").getUTCHours() //=> 0


Alternatively you could ignore the time zone, and read the dates in local time. This can be done by chopping of the Z which denotes UTC.
const horizont_start = "2024-05-01T00:00:00Z".replace('Z', '');
console.log(new Date(horizont_start)); // without the Z
// Wed May 01 2024 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Uzbekistan Standard Time)

WARNING: Do note that 2024-05-01T00:00:00Z and 2024-05-01T00:00:00+05:00 are two different moments in time:
2024-05-01T00:00:00Z = 2024-05-01T05:00:00+05:00
2024-04-30T19:00:00Z = 2024-05-01T00:00:00+05:00

So if the exact moment in time is important you do NOT want to use this method.

The issue happens only when there is no horizont_start or no horizont_end from the backend. The dates created in such cases are based on the locale time zone. In all other cases, the dates are created based on the UTC time zone. This is the conflict occurs in the code.
The solution is to use Date.UTC function to create dates always with respect to UTC time in all cases. This solution also has been demoed below.
Please see below for a detailed review of the case.
The following two dates have no timezone offset specified, instead there is only a literal Z. It means that it is the UTC time.
"horizont_start": "2024-05-01T00:00:00Z"
"horizont_end": "2025-01-26T00:00:00Z",

Therefore the following two new date objects will also be in UTC time.
const horizont_start = '2024-05-01T00:00:00Z';
const horizont_end = '2025-01-26T00:00:00Z';
const date_horizont_start = new Date(horizont_start);
const date_horizont_end = new Date(horizont_end);
console.log(date_horizont_start); //2024-05-01T00:00:00.000Z UTC time
console.log(date_horizont_end); // 2025-01-26T00:00:00.000Z UTC time

However, when there is no horizont_start or horizont_end dates from the backend, there are issues in the present code. The following two dates are with respect to the locale time zone. It is not with respect to UTC as it is in the above cases.
It may require a close attention over here
Further on the same point, new Date (2014, 0, 1) below creates a date value with respect to the local time zone - Asia/Calcutta, which is ahead of UTC by 5.30 hh:mm. This is quite clear from the console log. The console log over here shows date in UTC timezone which is trailing by 5.30 hh:mm. The same happens for the date in date_horizont_end as well.
Ideally what would have happened was new Date(2014, 0, 1) should have created with respect to UTC time, if it was the case, the console log would have shown the same date value, it would not have been trailing by 5.30 hh:mm. The solution below address the issue.
const horizont_start = null;
const horizont_end = null;
const date_horizont_start = new Date(2014, 0, 1);
const date_horizont_end = new Date(new Date());
console.log(date_horizont_start); // 2013-12-31T18:30:00.000Z UTC time trailing by 5.30 hh:mm
console.log(date_horizont_end); // 2024-10-05T05:50:22.716Z UTC time trailing by 5.30 hh:mm

The solution is to use Date.UTC in this case as well, as below. This will keep UTC time in either case.
const horizont_start = null;
const horizont_end = null;
const date_horizont_start = new Date(Date.UTC(2014, 0, 1));
const date_horizont_end = new Date(
  Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDay())
);
console.log(date_horizont_start); // 2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z UTC time
console.log(date_horizont_end); // 2024-10-06T00:00:00.000Z UTC time

The code may require to modify as below:
<NewGanttChart
    start={
        new Date(
            gantt?.horizont_start ||
                new Date(
                    Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(),
                    0,
                    1)
                )
        )
    }
    end={
        new Date(
            gantt?.horizont_end ||
                new Date(
  Date.UTC(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDay())
)

        )
    }
    data={gantt?.machine_types || []}
    isTooltip={true}
    tooltip={tooltip}
/>


So, i've decided to get timeZoneOffSet and use it in my function like this and it's working for me:
const timeAxis = useMemo(() => {
        const startOffset = start.getTimezoneOffset()
        const endOffset = end.getTimezoneOffset()

        const adjustedStart = new Date(
            start.getTime() + startOffset * 60 * 1000
        )

        const adjustedEnd = new Date(end.getTime() + endOffset * 60 * 1000)

        const axisLength = Math.ceil(
            (adjustedEnd - adjustedStart) / (measure * 60 * 60 * 1000)
        )

        const axisDates = new Array(axisLength).fill(0).map((_, i) => {
            const date = new Date(adjustedStart.getTime())
            const newDate = new Date(
                date.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * measure * i
            )

            return newDate.getTime()
        })

        return axisDates
    }, [end, measure, start])


